# Adding @ (at) sign to laravel route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to add @ symbol to url. Just like [this](https://laracasts.com/@splendidkeen). I have tried this in web.php.
`Route::get('/@{user}', 'ProfilesController@show');`
 It did not work. Then I tried `Route::get('/@/{user}', 'ProfilesController@show');`
 It worked but how can I remove the (slash) '/' between @ symbol and user id ?

User model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'nick';
}
```

ProfilesController:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return view('profiles.show', [
        'profileUser' => $user
    ]);
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/@{user}', 'ProfilesController@show');
```

Comment: `'/@{id}'` work very well. Show error code.

Comment: Why do you need to use @ in the first place?

Comment: @wolacinio "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." Every profile has a unique nick and I set this nick to slug with public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'nick';
    } can this be caused by this problem

Comment: @Option Because I created a search function that uses the @ sign to search profile. When I run this function it goes to that url.

Comment: Show your model and controller files.

Comment: @Jackowski I thought that. Unfortunately I do not have another option.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have it should work. Check your controller code to make sure you are accepting the variable. The code below is what we have working on our site.

**web.php**

  `Route::get('/@{username}', [
    'as' => 'profile', 
    'uses' => 'ProfilesController@show'
  ]);`

**ProfilesController.php**

  `public function show($username){
    ...
  }`

Answer (score -1):

You are better off refactoring your code.. the @ sign is a reserved character as is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, and a better answer than a downvote.